# Appending variable that is modified in a for loop doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, list

I have this code:

```
lst = []
given = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
result = []

for item in given:
    lst.append(item)
    print(lst)
    result.append(lst)

print(result)
```

My expected result is `[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], ...]`, but displayed result is `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ...]` with `12345` repeated 5 times. What is wrong?

`lst` printed is as expected, which is `[1]` for the first loop, [`1, 2]` for the second loop, and so on.

Comment: Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 3):

Python doesn't create copy of `lst` every time when you append it to `result`, it just inserts reference. As a result you get list with N references to same list.

To create a copy of `lst` you can use `lst.copy()`. Also list slice operator works same `lst[:]`.

Shortened version of your code:

```
given = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
result = [given[0 : i + 1] for i in range(len(given))]
print(result)
```

Result:

```
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: Nice listcomps!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are appending the list as such which is equivalent to appending the reference object to the original list. Therefore, whenever the original list is modified, the changes are reflected in the places where the reference is created, in this case in `result`. As you keep iterating via the for loop, all your references appended in `result` keep getting updated with the latest value of `lst`. The final result is that at the end of the for loop, you have appended 5 references to the original list `lst` and all of them store the latest value of `lst` being `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

There are several ways to avoid this. What you need is to copy only the values. One of them is to use `lst[:]`. other way is to use `lst.copy()`

```
for item in given:
    lst.append(item)
    print(lst)
    result.append(lst[:])

print (result)
# [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

List is a mutable data type, there is only one copy in memory for a list unless you explicitly `copy` it to another variable. So

```
result.append(lst)
```

just appends a reference of the real copy and all the refercences point to the same copy.

In conclusion, you should learn about mutable/immutable data types and reference count in python.

Comment: mutable/immutable is irrelevant. It will behave the same way, immutable values simply lack mutator methods...

Comment: a = 1
    result = []
    while a < 10:
        a += 1
        result.append(a)

    print(result)   # output [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Answer (score 0):

Append `lst.copy()` gives the right output.

```
lst = []
given = [1,2,3,4,5]
result = []

for item in given:
    lst.append(item)
    print(lst)
    result.append(lst.copy())

print(result)
```